# How to do REGEX (Groovy) to select words "She","Shell" with REGEX = "She"?

Tags: regex, groovy

I am newbie on REGEX, I am trying to get the words "She" and "Shell" only, not ashes with this program (Groovy).  I have been working on the for some time.

```
saying = 'She wishes for Shells not ashes'
println saying
def pattern = ~/\bShe*\b/
def matcher = pattern.matcher(saying)
def count = matcher.getCount()
println "Matches = ${count}"
for (i in 0..<count) {
    print matcher[i] + " "
}
```

Output:
She wishes for Shells not ashes
Matches = 1
She

REGEX does not work like Windows CMD e.g dir W*  to list folder or files begins with W.  What did I do wrong?

Many Thanks when you answer this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular expressions the `*` is *not* the same as a wildcard (match any characters).

It is a *quantifier* that modifies whatever is immediately before it and means "zero or more". Your regular expression matches `Sh` followed by zero or more `e`. So it will match these strings:

```
Sh
She
Shee
Sheee
etc...
```

What you probably mean is `\w*` to match any word characters.

```
/\bShe\w*\b/
```

Also note that in regular expressions "word characters" are considered to be letters, numbers or the underscore. So a sequence of word characters is different from what is regarded as a "word" in human languages. It is in fact not easy to correctly identify words using regular expressions alone, so if you need to match words in a specific language you should use a natural language processing library and/or a dictionary instead of a regular expression.